# Should IO run inline during propagation?

Tags: haskell, idris, frp

I am trying to write an FRP library in Idris. This library designed to be run in a single thread environment. Future implement `Monad` and `Align`. I want to implement functions with these simplified type signatures:

```
createFutureResolveLater : (Future a, a -> IO ()) -- later time

createFutureResolveNow : a -> IO (Future a) -- current time

pure : a -> Future a -- before everything

align : Future a -> Future a -> Future (These a b) -- min of two times

join : Future (Future a)) -> Future a -- max of two times

exeEvent : Future (IO a) -> IO (Future a) -- ??

simultaneous : Future a -> Future b -> Future Bool -- min of two times

subFuture : Future a -> (a -> IO ()) -> IO ()
```

In seems obvious to me that

```
simultaneous a a, simultaneous a (fmap f a), etc.
```

should be a future that resolves to true.

In

```
do
    oe <- exeEvent ie
    let s = simultaneous oe ie
    ...
```

should s resolve to true?

In reactive-banana, s would be false. See mapEventIO in  http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana-1.2.1.0/docs/Reactive-Banana-Frameworks.html

In reflex, s would also mostly likely be false. See performEvent in https://daig.github.io/reflex/Reflex-PerformEvent-Class.html

Why do these library authors choose for s to be false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to figure out what you are asking.  I think you are wondering how to account for `IO` actions that take time, no?  Because if the `IO` action was instantaneous this would not be a question.  Though there is still a question for me, which is does the `IO` action block until the future occurs or does it schedule it asynchronously?

If this is a non-blocking call, I would say it should wait until the `IO` action completes.  (I would also call it `schedFuture` or some such to be clear that it doesn't block.)  Otherwise you could have the case of the `Future`'s time being in the past, yet the value still not being available, which could screw up the logic of functions that merge events, etc.

If this is a blocking call, I would instead provide

```
waitFuture :: Future a -> IO a
```

and let the user deal with the rest (e.g. they could `fmap (const x)` on the original future if they wanted to preserve the time, they could use `now :: IO (Future ())` if they wanted it when the action completes, etc.).  It might be worth providing combinators for those if you can come up with good names for them, otherwise they are easy enough that I'd just punt.

I have also found it helpful when making systems like this to distinguish between "morally instantaneous" `IO` actions and actions that might block.  I suppose this is parallel to javascript's distinction between async and regular stack calls.  There are a lot of fuzzy questions like this, and the corresponding obvious answers tend to depend on this distinction.

Comment: Everything in the library will be single threaded async with callbacks and  no blocking.

Comment: I read your answer a few times. I believe you are saying that they should occur simultaneously, correct?

Comment: Why do reflex and reactive-banana seem to think that they should not be simultaneous?